# .htaccess mod_rewrite.c removing php extension not working on godaddy servers

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have seen this problem posed on several sites with their solution, which doesn't seem to be working for me.

I am trying to turn somesite.com/services.php into somesite.com/services

**My .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
</IfModule>
```

adding the

```
Options -MultiViews
```

was most peoples solution to the problem. This didn't work for me.

This creates an issue when searching for my services.php file, looking in a directory location after duplicating the path for the .com

```
/somesite.com/somesite.com/services.php

The requested URL /somesite.com/somesite.com/services.php was not found on this server.
```

I have a feeling this is a simple fix. I am hoping the stackoverflow army can correct my error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^.]+).html$
    RewriteRule ^.* %1.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

And Possible Duplicate of [htaccess not working on godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17101686/4595675)

Comment: This has gotten me a little closer "The requested URL /somesite.com/services was not found on this server." Appears it is looking for the file without the .php now?